# How can I drill my wall if it contains flint?

Tags: walls, drill

I live in an old victorian house.  Some of the walls seem to have pebbles inside then you get so far and there is flint, the drill won't go any further.  Its a nightmare putting anything on the wall!

Is there anything I can use to drill through this stone?!!  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a concrete drill bit?

Comment: just used an sds hammer drill and it worked wonders!

Comment: You can write that as an answer to your own question, and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

For flint you will need a diamond coated drill bit, SDS plus drill bits on hammer won't cut it. If the item is big try to drill somewhere else where the motar is. Flint is a nightmare!

Answer (score 1):

The first drill to try in this situation would be a standard hammer drill. If this was not powerful enough you could try a SDS Hammer Drill.